# Solve polynomial congruence using Hensel's lemma

Tags: calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Solve $x^4+2x+46 \equiv 0$ $(\mod 4375 )$ for x.

.

My attempt:

$x^4+2x+46 \equiv 0$ $(\mod 5^47 )$
breaks down to 
a Chinese Remainder Problem with the 2 following congruence's':

(1) $x^4+2x+46 \equiv 0$ $(\mod 7 )$ which by inspection is x $\equiv 2,6 (\mod 7)$

and

(2) $x^4+2x+46 \equiv 0$ $(\mod 5^4)$

It's (2) that's really difficult for me and I know I am supposed to use Hensel's Lemma, can any one help with this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there a bunch's of Hensel's Lemma examples and theory on the internet. Google them.

Comment: I'm just having a difficult time understanding my textbook and other online resources on Hensels' lemma.
I took the derivative and there were 4 non zero solutions to f'(x) mod (5) and I just see no progress.

Comment: Can I just choose one of 0,1,2,-1 to lift?
That is since f'(0), f'(1), f'(2), f'(-1) are non-zero mod 5.

Comment: Check the answer it should be enough.

Comment: On (1), you should be getting x = 1 or x = 3. I have no idea how you managed to get 2 and 6 as solutions but they're wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Hensel lemma states that if there exist integer $x$ such that:

$$f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod {p^k} \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad f'(x) \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

then there exist integer $s$ such that:

$$f(s) \equiv 0 \pmod {p^{k+m}} \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad s \equiv r \pmod {p^k}$$

Now it's obvious that $s = r + tp^k$ for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now let's move to the problem. Find a solution for the equation:

$$x^4 + 2x + 46 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$

Since $x\equiv 0 \pmod 5$ obviously isn't solution, Fermat's Little Theorem come in use so we have:

$$x^4 + 2x + 46 \equiv 1 + 2x + 46 \equiv 2x + 47 \equiv 2x + 52 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$

From this obviously $x \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ is a solution. So take $x_1 = 4$

Now find the derivative of the function. This is easy and we have:

$$f'(x) = 4x^3 + 2$$

Now we need to find a solution: $f(x_2) \equiv 0 \pmod {5^2}$ i.e. $f(x_1 + 5t) \equiv 0 \pmod {5^2}$. The last expression is equivalent to:

$$f(x_1) + 5tf'(x_1) \equiv \pmod {5^2}$$

Now substitute $x_1 = 4$ and we have:

$$f(4) + 5tf'(4) \equiv 0 \pmod {5^2}$$
$$310 + 5t \cdot 258 \equiv 0 \pmod {5^2}$$

Divide with $5$.

$$62 + 258t \equiv 2 + 3t \equiv \pmod 5$$

From this we get: $t \equiv 1 \pmod 5$. Choose $t=1$ and we have: $x_2 = x_1 + 5t = 9$

So now we have $f(9) \equiv 0 \pmod {5^2}$...

Did you get the concept. Can you continue on your own and lift the exponent first to $3$ and then to $4$?

Comment: @Adam Staples Here's a little help $x_3 = 9$ and $x_4 = 509$. So the solution is $x \equiv 509 \pmod {5^4}$